# 'name': ambiguous symbol VisualStudio 2015

Tags: c++, symbols

I so my project to migrate to Visual Studio 2015.
However I got stuck when I saw that receive 13 errors.

Error   C2872   'data': ambiguous symbol
Error   C2872   'size': ambiguous symbol

Before you migrate to vss2015 everything work perfectly, I can not understand why we have moved the program after receiving this error.

Here is my Jpeg.h

```
#pragma once
int jpeg_save(unsigned char*data, int width, int height, int quality, const char*filename);
int jpeg_save_to_file(unsigned char*data, int width, int height, int quality, FILE*fi);
int jpeg_save_to_mem(unsigned char*data, int width, int height, int quality, unsigned char*dest, int destsize);
int jpeg_load(const char*filename, unsigned char**dest, int*width, int*height);
int jpeg_load_from_mem(unsigned char*_data, int size, unsigned char*dest, int width, int height);
```

And here is my jpeg.cpp

```
void mem_init_source (j_decompress_ptr cinfo)
{
    struct jpeg_source_mgr* mgr = cinfo->src;
    mgr->next_input_byte = data;
    mgr->bytes_in_buffer = size;
}
```

I get the error for "data" and also for "size" symbol.

Best regards.

Comment: Is everything right with your namespaces ? Maybe you have other occurrences of `data` and `size` and the compiler can not resolve which one you are calling, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: Take  a look at full .cpp  http://pastebin.com/1VkujGPq

Comment: looks like pure C code

Answer (score 1):

Some of your functions have local variables named data and size, resulting in conflicts with global variables of the same names.

```
static unsigned char*data;
static int size;
...
int jpeg_save_to_file(unsigned char*data, int width, int height, int quality, FILE*fi);
int jpeg_load_from_mem(unsigned char*_data, int size, unsigned char*dest, int width, int height);
...
```

... resulting in conflicts when you compile your code

Answer (score 0):

For instance you have a global variable data and then you have a function argument named data so the compiler is confused which to use - I know I would.

Simplest to get around this is to put a namespace around your global variables, that way it is more clear when you are accessing the global variable or the local variable.

E.g.

```
namespace globals
{
  static FILE*fi;
  static JOCTET * buffer;
  static unsigned char*dest;
  static int len;
  static int destlen;
  static unsigned char*data;
  static int pos;
  static int size;
};

...
int jpeg_save(unsigned char*data, int width, int height, int quality, const char*filename)
{
  globals::data = ...;
}
```

alt. use unnamed namespace

```
namespace
{
  static FILE* fi;
  ...
}

...

::fi = fopen(...);
```

Comment: I sended you an gmail hangouts. Answer me :D

Comment: Did you tried changing the names of your functions parameters ?